# getTermSetsByName does not return an instance of TermSet

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, client-object-model, mms

Following code does not work correctly

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var tSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
var ts = tSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var tset = ts.getTermSetsByName("myTermSet", 1033); 
var terms = tset.get_terms();
```

It returns an error and says `Object doesn't support property or method get_terms`

But this code returns all terms correctly

```
var termSetId = "b48ce920-3051-4e96-b9af-55ddc1fa3f2b";
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var tSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
var ts = tSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var tset = ts.getTermSet(termSetId);
var terms = tset.get_terms();
```

I don't want to use the guid of the term set inside my code. How do I make the first code snippet to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method `getTermSetsByName` returns a [collection of termsets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312638%28v=office.15%29.aspx), not a single termset, so you should probably do something like:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var tSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
var ts = tSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var tset = ts.getTermSetsByName("myTermSet", 1033); 
var terms = tset.getByName("myTermSet")
```

or get it by index (feels risky):

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var tSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
var ts = tSession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var tset = ts.getTermSetsByName("myTermSet", 1033); 
var terms = tset.itemAt(0);
```

I have not tried the codes above, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: thanks, It still does not return any term set.

Comment: And you are executing the code?